# Axios - cannot change variable data value

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, axios, vue-cli-3

I tried to change the variable data using axios, i am using vue-axios and vue cli 3.

This is the code:

```js
const qs = require('qs')
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data: function () {
    return {
      email: null,
      errEmail: false,
      baseUrl: 'https://www.example.com/isemail.php'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next: function () {
    },
    err: function () {
      this.axios.post(this.baseUrl + 'functions/isEmail.php', qs.stringify({
        value: this.email
      }))
        .then(function (resp) {
          this.errEmail = true
        })
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-if="errEmail">Target Success</div>
```

Actually i am trying change the errEmail variable depend on the server callback like this:

```
this.errEmail = resp.data.isemail
```

but using constant seems not working too.

Comment: You need to use an arrow function for the `then()` callback, or `this` inside the function will refer to the function itself, not your Vue app context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
.then(function (resp) {
  this.errEmail = true
})
```

to this

```
.then((resp) => {
  this.errEmail = true
})
```

Or manually bind `this`

```
   .then(function (resp) {
      this.errEmail = true
    }.bind(this))
```